# How to switch installed Python versions in Windows?

Tags: python, windows, path

I have 3 versions  of Python installed on C:

```
C:\Python27
C:\Python30
C:\Python33
```

I was using 2.7 version, tried to switch to 3.3 changing the path in Environment Vars and nothing had changed, not even restarting.
The old version is being used with no mention to it in Path string.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Did you change the PATH in a shell or in the main environment variable dialog? You need to set it in the latter for it to persist.

Comment: @KevinThibedeau, only in the Windows GUI (System > Advanced Configs > Env. Vars > ...)

Comment: You should have the new [py.exe launcher](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows). Check the file association in the command prompt (cmd.exe): `for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %i in ('assoc .py') do @(ftype %i)`. The default all-user installation for 3.3 should have set it to `Python.File="C:\Windows\py.exe" "%1" %*`.

Comment: Add first lines, like `#!/usr/bin/env python27`, `#!/usr/bin/env python3`, etc to a test script and see if the the specified interpreter gets invoked.

Comment: @martineau - that won't work on Windows. Although if you use the py.exe launcher that eryksun mentioned, you can do something similar.

Comment: @Mike: I'm assuming they have py launcher installed since they have Python 3 installed.

Comment: Yeah, but the command would be something like `#! python3`, not `#!/usr/bin/env python27` which is *nix only

Comment: @MikeDriscoll, the launcher supports the following [virtual paths](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ab2c023a9432/PC/launcher.c#l667): `/usr/bin/env`, `/usr/bin`, and `/usr/local/bin`. It also supports an empty virtual path for shebangs such as `!#python3`. It also supports commands defined in `%localappdata%\py.ini` (e.g. you can create virtual commands to run PyPy or IronPython).

Comment: Good to know. I stand corrected